# separating hyperplane theorem proof

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I need help understanding the last part of this proof, the lemma they are refering too is just a lemma about convex sets that shows us that p is unique:

[image]

I do not see how H* separates C and z.

The equation for H* is:

$(z-p)^Tx=\frac{(z-p)^T(z+p)}{2}=\frac{|z|^2-|p|^2}{2}$

And the elements in C sattisfies:

$(z-p)^Tx \le (z-p)^Tp$.

Now from what I understand in order for it to strongly separate we must have.

$(z-p)^Tp < \frac{|z|^2-|p|^2}{2}<(z-p)^Tz$.

Is it correct that this is what we must have? Is this inequality obvious?

Comment: You have $(z-p)^T z > (z-p)^T p$, since $(z-p)^T z - (z-p)^T p = \lVert z-p\rVert^2$. So for $m = \frac{1}{2}(z+p)$, we have $(z-p)^T p < (z-p)^T m < (z-p)^T z$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, that was very clever of you!